# ios 7 UITabBarController not working after setSelectedIndex

Tags: ios7, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I have problem with my UITabBarController. After I change tab using

```
tabBarController setSelectedIndex:
```

on ios 7 tab not responding on clicks, it works on ios 6 well.

Is there any problem related to UITabBarController in ios7?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Could you provide some details ? What i understand is that you're able to change selected tab bar, but after when you tap another tab, it's no more changing. is it your issu e ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after moving to xcode5 ios 7 and what I found was that calling the popToRootViewControllerAnimated: before the setSelectedIndex: was causing the problem.

Make sure you have this order

```
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```